# Mixed up wires in a j-box, need a little help

Tags: wiring

Had a leak in my ceiling a few days ago, and in my haste to remove the light fixture there, I failed to pay attention to how the wires were grouped together in this jbox (picture below) and I need to figure out how to put it back.

The bottom right wires coming in are from the light switch to control this light; the other three go to other light fixtures nearby.

Can someone help me figure out what wires go where by this picture? The black wires thankfully stayed together, but I need help understanding what's going on with the white wires.

I have a multimeter to check things, but I'm not an experienced electrician and I don't want to mix anything up here.

(let me know if any additional pictures will help)

[image: This is the mess of wires I'm concerned about]

[image]

Comment: Add a picture of the wires at the switch.  I think you might have a switch loop and the white wire from the switch should be marked black(or red).

Comment: added picture of the switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an old style switch loop, incorrectly wired by the old-style rules that permitted switch loops.

The **hot** white wire to the switch should be connected to the hots (group of black wires) and should be **marked** as a hot wire at both ends, here and the switch box, (black or red or any other hot color tape or paint.) Neither of those is what you have here.

If not correcting it, **at least** mark the white from the switch with black or red before connecting that white to the black on the fixture, and the white grouped with whites to the white on the fixture, which is presumably how it was wired before. The white to another fixture would also join the white neutral group, presumably.

If correcting it, the marked white from the switch joins the black group, and the black from the switch goes to the fixture black.

This is not acceptable in new work (since NEC 2011) but is so common as to be standard in old work from before that time. But the correct standard approach is the hot white gets marked, and the switched hot is the black.

Comment: To confirm that: The box with the switch should have only one cable coming into it, and the switch should be connected to black and white in that cable. If you see something else....

Comment: Ok I pulled the switch away from the wall and sure enough, it has a black and white wire. So it sounds to me I need to:  1) mark the single white wire from the switch with a  black marking.  2) put those two bare white wires and the white from the fixture into a wire nut and 3) put the black from the fixture in with the white from the switch.

Comment: If you're correcting, go ahead and correct. Put the marked white to the switch with the other blacks, and the black from the switch to the fixture black. Also check the integrity of the current white join, as the other white may have pulled out of it, meaning it might be loose. It should be tight and nothing should pull out.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that... it initially sounded like there was more to do than just swap those switch wires. New update: 1) mark the switch white wire; 2) pull the switch black from the bunch and use for fixture; 3) put the marked white with the black bunch; 4) use the existing white bunch for the fixture white and ensure all are connected.

Comment: Just to close the loop here, I made the changes and just tested that everything is working as expected. Thank you @Ecnerwal for your answer.